# Flutter open module in Xcode gives error when trying to open from android studio?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, android-studio, dart

In my flutter project I'm trying to run the iOS version to debug. But when I try to open the iOS module in Xcode from Android studio it gives me following error.

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/jasondwaku/Documents/FlutterProjects/ClubRoom/clubroom/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:694:12: warning: variable 'best_offset' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
              (best_offset << MAX_LENGTH_BITS) | (uint32_t)best_length;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/jasondwaku/Documents/FlutterProjects/ClubRoom/clubroom/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:626:20: note: initialize the variable 'best_offset' to silence this warning
        int best_offset;
                       ^
                        = 0
    1 warning generated.
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.7.4/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPhotoAssetUtil.m:17:44: warning: 'UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Will be removed in a future release, use PHPicker. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
                                               ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jasondwaku/Documents/FlutterProjects/ClubRoom/clubroom/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIImagePickerController.h:62:51: note: 'UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    UIKIT_EXTERN UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey const UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL API_DEPRECATED("Will be removed in a future release, use PHPicker.", ios(4.1, 11.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos); // an NSURL that references an asset in the AssetsLibrary framework
                                                      ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.7.4/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPhotoAssetUtil.m:21:47: warning: 'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11 - Will be removed in a future release [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[ referenceURL ]
                                                  ^
    In module 'Photos' imported from /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.7.4/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPhotoAssetUtil.h:6:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework/Headers/PHAsset.h:74:1: note: 'fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    + (PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *)fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)assetURLs options:(nullable PHFetchOptions *)options API_DEPRECATED("Will be removed in a future release", ios(8, 11), tvos(8, 11)) API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/jasondwaku/Documents/FlutterProjects/ClubRoom/clubroom/ios/Pods/SDWebImageWebPCoder/SDWebImageWebPCoder/Classes/SDImageWebPCoder.m:608:33: warning: 'CGColorSpaceCreateWithICCProfile' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - No longer supported [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                    colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateWithICCProfile((__bridge CFDataRef)profileData);
                                    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jasondwaku/Documents/FlutterProjects/ClubRoom/clubroom/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/SDWebImageWebPCoder/SDWebImageWebPCoder-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'CoreGraphics' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIBezierPath.h:10:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGColorSpace.h:449:38: note: 'CGColorSpaceCreateWithICCProfile' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    CG_EXTERN CGColorSpaceRef __nullable CGColorSpaceCreateWithICCProfile(CFDataRef cg_nullable data)
                                         ^
    1 warning generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    12 warnings generated.
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.0.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:39:18: warning: direct comparison of a string literal has undefined behavior [-Wobjc-string-compare]
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.0.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:39:18: note: use 'isEqual:' instead
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^~
           [          isEqual:       ]
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.0.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:82:18: warning: direct comparison of a string literal has undefined behavior [-Wobjc-string-compare]
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.0.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:82:18: note: use 'isEqual:' instead
        if(imageType == @"image/webp") {
                     ^~
           [          isEqual:       ]
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.0.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:109:16: warning: unused variable 'swf' [-Wunused-variable]
        const char swf[3] = {'F', 'W', 'S'};
                   ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress-1.0.0/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:110:16: warning: unused variable 'swc' [-Wunused-variable]
        const char swc[3] = {'C', 'W', 'S'};
                   ^
    4 warnings generated.
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:29:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:34:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:62:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:66:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:62:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:66:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:29:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:34:16: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                   ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariBrowserOptions.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariBrowserOptions: Options<SafariViewController> {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:62:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:66:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:62:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:66:12: warning: unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
               ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/SafariViewController/SafariViewController.swift:12:14: note: enclosing scope here
    public class SafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, FlutterPlugin, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
                 ^
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Classes/Types/URLCredential.swift:14:25: warning: comparing non-optional value of type '[Any]' to 'nil' always returns true
            if certificates != nil {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-8.0.0-dev.15/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:6:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/jasondwaku/Documents/FlutterProjects/ClubRoom/clubroom/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_core/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
    In file included from /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:11:
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:9:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin': '/Users/jasondwaku/Documents/FlutterProjects/ClubRoom/clubroom/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
    #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    /Users/jasondwaku/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-8.0.0-dev.15/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:6:9: fatal error: could not build module 'firebase_core'
    #import <firebase_core/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    2 errors generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Encountered error while building for simulator.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My pub spec looks like below

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.15
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  connectivity: ^3.0.3
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  toggle_switch: ^0.1.8
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  implicitly_animated_reorderable_list: ^0.4.0
  country_pickers: ^2.0.0
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  flappy_search_bar: ^1.7.2
  package_info: ^2.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.7.4 
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.0.0
  mime: ^1.0.0
  http_parser: ^4.0.0  #^3.1.4
  http: ^0.13.0 #^0.12.2
  provider: ^5.0.0
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2  
  multi_select_flutter: ^4.0.0
  device_info: ^2.0.0

  overlay_support: ^1.2.1
  rename: ^1.3.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create a new iOS project. Delete or Rename the iOS folder and run the following commands.

- flutter clean
- flutter create -i swift .